# c++でのスタック構造について

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム, スタック

逆ポーランドを実装しようとした際に、 `while(scanf("%s", s) != EOF)` で入力を受け取った後に `if(s[0] == '+')` で条件分岐が始まるのですが、なぜ `s[0]` と配列 `s` のインデックスを `0` に固定したままでも良いのでしょうか？
`s[0]` の次は `s[1]` 、さらに `s[2]` とインデックスを増やしていき、最終的に `s[n]` が `EOF` なら終了するとイメージしているのですが、何が違うのでしょうか？

**ソースコード**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int top, S[1000];

void push(int x) {
    S[++top] = x;
}

int pop() {
    top--;
    return S[top+1];
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    top = 0;
    char s[100];

    while(scanf("%s", s) != EOF) {
        if(s[0] == '+') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a + b);
        } else if (s[0] == '-') {
            b = pop();
            a = pop();
            push(a - b);
        } else if (s[0] == '*') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a * b);
        } else {
            push(atoi(s));
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop());

    return 0;
}
```

また、

```
int main() {
    int a, b;
    top = 0;
    char s;

    while(scanf("%c", s) != EOF) {
        if(s == '+') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a + b);
        } else if (s == '-') {
            b = pop();
            a = pop();
            push(a - b);
        } else if (s == '*') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a * b);
        } else {
            push(atoi(s));
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop());

    return 0;
}
```

と、上記のようにchar s[100]をchar sに、while(scanf("%s", s) != EOF)をwhile(scanf("%c", s) != EOF)に、if(s[0]== '+') をif(s == '+') に変えた場合うまくいかないのですが、理由がわかりません。
1 + 1 のように入力する数字を1桁に絞ってます。

Answer (score 1):

scanfの%s指定子は空白類文字(半角スペースや改行)区切りに標準入力への文字列を入れていく物です
(char s[100]へガツンと一括入力される訳ではありません)

例えば「11 12 +」という入力がある場合

1回目のsには「11」
2回目のsには「12」
3回目のsには「+」

がそれぞれ入ります

各記号の場合、入力毎の1文字目しか見なくても問題がないので
s[0]を指定しているのだと思います。

余談ですが、多分どこかの本に出ている例題だったりしませんか？
入力例のような物があれば、デバッガやprintfをはさみつつ動作を確認すると分かりやすいかもしれません
(下記は一例です)

```cpp
int main() {
    int a, b;
    top = 0;
    char s[100];
    int cnt = 1;

    while(scanf("%s", s) != EOF) {
        printf("%d回目:%s\n",cnt,s);
        if(s[0] == '+') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a + b);
        } else if (s[0] == '-') {
            b = pop();
            a = pop();
            push(a - b);
        } else if (s[0] == '*') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a * b);
        } else {
            push(atoi(s));
        }
        ++cnt;
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop());

    return 0;
}
```

※追記質問について
以下の3点に問題がありそうです。
（文末に修正コードを記述しましたので、照らし合わせつつ確認してみて下さい)

1.scanfの第2引数へポインタを指定していない
scanfには格納オブジェクトのポインタを指定する必要が有ります。
配列型から要素型(char [100]→char)に変更していますので、この場合ポインタを取る形へ修正する必要が有ります

2.atoiへ文字列へのポインタを指定していない
atoiは文字列をint型の数値へ変換する関数ですので、文字を変換することは出来ません

文字を数値にしたい場合は、「対象の文字 - '0'」と記述する必要が有ります
(言語規格において、この操作はどのプラットフォームでも正しく動作する事が間接的に保証されています)
例:
char s = '3'
int value = s - '0';

3.改行文字や空白文字を数値として入力してしまう
%sと違い空白類文字を飛ばしてくれないので
空白や改行が入力された時に数値として認識してしまいます

```cpp
    while(scanf("%c", s) != EOF) { ←1.空白が入力された時
        if(s == '+') {             ←2.+ではない
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a + b);
        } else if (s == '-') {     ←3.-でもない
            b = pop();
            a = pop();
            push(a - b);
        } else if (s == '*') {     ←4.*でもない
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a * b);
        } else {                   ←5.数値じゃないのに数値として入ってしまう
            push(atoi(s));
        }
    }
```

上記の問題点を修正して少し書き直してみました

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int top, S[1000];

void push(int x) {
    S[++top] = x;
}

int pop() {
    top--;
    return S[top+1];
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    top = 0;
    char s;

    while(scanf("%c", &s) != EOF) { //1.scanfの第2引数をポインタに修正
        if(s == '+') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a + b);
        } else if (s == '-') {
            b = pop();
            a = pop();
            push(a - b);
        } else if (s == '*') {
            a = pop();
            b = pop();
            push(a * b);
        } else if(isspace(s)){     //3.改行文字や空白文字が入ってきたら何もせずに次へ
            /* do nothing */
        } else {
            push(s - '0');         //2.atoiが使用出来ないので、s-'0'を使用するように修正
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop());

    return 0;
}
```

上記回答や元ソースコードと照らし合わせて確認してみて下さい

Comment: 詳しくありがとうございます。助かりました。重ねての疑問なのですが、char s[100]をchar sに、while(scanf("%s", s) != EOF)をwhile(scanf("%c", s) != EOF)に、if(s[0]== '+') をif(s == '+') に変えた場合うまくいかないのですが、理由がわかりません。コード全体は質問に追記するのでもしよろしければそちらもお願いします。

Comment: 確認ありがとうございます。stackoverflowのルールについて少し調べてみたのですが、
質問内容の大幅変更はあまり思わしくないようです。(私も知りませんでした) [回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558/%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e5%be%8c%e3%81%ae%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%a7%e5%b9%85%e3%81%aa%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%81%ae%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%99%e3%81%b9%e3%81%8d%e3%81%8b)
今後質問変更される際にはちょっと気を配ったほうが良いのかもしれませんね。(私も気をつけます)

Comment: 追記質問について編集しました。ご確認下さい

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問内容変更のルールに関しましては把握不足でした、以後気をつけます。質問への回答に関しましてもありがとうございます。とても分かりやすく、さらにコードまで書いていただいて申し訳ないです。勉強の励みにもなりました。今回は本当にありがとうございました。